# Find one of two elements without fail in Cypress

Tags: javascript, xpath, cypress

I am doing automation testing using Cypress with Javascript.

**Question/Issue**

I have one scenario in which one of two elements should be available on the screen. Is it possible to handle this scenario?

**Description**

Inside kebab menu, multiple options are available and I have to check that required options should be visible. One of them is 'Set active'/Set inactive'. If the element is active, menu displays 'Set inactive' and vice-versa. Now I want to check that 'Set active/Set inactive' should be visible. For that I used `cy.xpath('//p[normalize-space()="Set active"]').should('be.visible')` and `cy.xpath('//p[normalize-space()="Set inactive"]').should('be.visible')`. But it fails if one of them not found. I also found that cypress not allowed try-catch.

How to handle this scenario?

I didn't find anything which is helpful.

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for selecting either/or element is [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Cypress have archived their `xpath` library, so you may wish to convert to CSS selectors.

The following should be the CSS selectors equivalent to the `xpath`. The comma between expression means take either/or element.

```js
cy.get('p:contains("Set active"), p:contains("Set inactive")')
```

My xpath is a bit rusty, I'm assuming `p[normalize-space()="Set active"]` means something like

> get the `<p>` element which has trimmed text of "Set active"

---

If you want to continue using `xpath`, there is the `|` operator that would do the same job as Multiple Selector.

```js
cy.xpath('//p[normalize-space()="Set active"] | //p[normalize-space()="Set inactive"]')
```